# XML File Gzip and PHP

Tags: php, xml, gzip

I'm try to read an external XML file with a PHP script, no wmatter what I try I get an "empty document" error. If I open the url in my browser I can access and read the xml fine.

There are numerous other posts on stack overflow with similar problem as mine but none of the solutions work in my case.

This is my code:

```
$url="http://xml.example.com";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("compress.zlib://$url", NULL, TRUE);
```

parser error : Document is empty in /home/admin/public_html/xml/index2.php on line 4

Apparently the 3rd party service requires that I explicitly request gzip compression.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working using curl then createing an XML object (I think!)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//print_r($output);

$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($output);
```

The results are compatible with my script and can be parsed to extract the data :0)